# svg trigger single animation

Tags: javascript, animation, svg

I figured out a problem with SVG I couldn't solve yet. Given is a svg with multiple animations depending on each other with the begin attribute. So the animations got different ID's like 'circle' and begin tags with values like 'circle.end'. These svg is rendered / used multiple times on the page. In the first point is it not valid to have a id multiple times. At the second point all svg's doing the animation depending on circle.end when I start it with circle.beginElement() of the first svg.

So how can I start an animation depending on another animation without using id's or how can I start the animation on only one svg?

Here is a sample code

```
<svg>
    <defs>
        <path d="asdasd" id="circle-image">
            <animateTransform id="circle" attributeName="transform" type="translate" from="0, 0" to="15, 0" begin="indefinite"/>
            <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="translate" from="15, 0" to="0, 0" begin="circle.end"/>
        </path>
    </defs>
</svg>
<svg viewBox="0 0 34 24" width="45px" height="24px" class="first">
     <use xlink:href="#circle-image"/>
</svg>
<svg viewBox="0 0 34 24" width="45px" height="24px" class="second">
     <use xlink:href="#circle-image"/>
</svg>
```

I want to somehow trigger .first #circle animation and .second #circle animation. The depending animation should only trigger within it's use element and not globally for all.
Can someone help here?

Thanks in advance
Regards Thomas

Comment: Multiple paths with multiple animations.

Comment: Then it would make more sense to inline the svg and add an iterator value to the id's I think. This would cause less characters.